# Moving characters around an array

Tags: c++

I am in the beginning stages of developing a game in C++ for school and I am having an issue. I have developed the 10x10 array and I am able to move one piece around the board freely, however when I add the second piece to the grid and try to move it neither piece will move here is my code for when I have one character on the board.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void displayArray(int, int);
void moveBoat(int, int);
int main()

{
int x=7;
int y=6;            

displayArray(x,y);
moveBoat(x,y);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void displayArray(int x, int y)
{
                    //0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
char Array[10][10]={{' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//0
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//1
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//2
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//3
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//4
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//5
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//6
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//7
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//8
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}//9
                    };

Array[x][y]='d';


for(int i=0; i<10; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cout << Array[i][j]  << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

void moveBoat(int x, int y)
{
int movement=0;
do{ 
cout<<"Boat Location X "<<x<<" Y "<<y<<endl;
cout<<"1.move up"<<endl;
cout<<"2.move down"<<endl;
cout<<"3.move left"<<endl;
cout<<"4.move right"<<endl;
cin>>movement;

    switch(movement)
    {
    case 1:
        if(x>0)
        {
        x=x-1;
        system("cls");
        displayArray(x,y);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        if(x<9)
        {
        x=x+1;
        system("cls");
        displayArray(x,y);
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 3:
        if(y>0)
        {
        y=y-1;
        system("cls");
        displayArray(x,y);
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 4:
        if(y<9)
        {
        y=y+1;
        system("cls");
        displayArray(x,y);
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"  <<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;


    }
}while(movement>-1);


}
```

And here is my code for two pieces

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void displayArray(int, int,int,int);
void moveBoat(int, int, int);
void moveEnemy(int, int, int);
int main()

{
int x=7;
int y=6;            
int a=3;
int b=4;
int turn=1;
do{
displayArray(x,y,a,b);
moveBoat(x,y,turn);
displayArray(x,y,a,b);
moveEnemy(a,b,turn);
}while(turn<3);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void displayArray(int x, int y,int a, int b)
{
                    //0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
char Array[10][10]={{' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//0
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//1
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//2
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//3
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//4
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//5
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//6
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//7
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},//8
                    {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}//9
                    };

Array[x][y]='d';
Array[a][b]='s';

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cout << Array[i][j]  << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

void moveBoat(int x, int y,int turn)
{
int movement=0;

cout<<"Boat Location X "<<x<<" Y "<<y<<endl;
cout<<"1.move up"<<endl;
cout<<"2.move down"<<endl;
cout<<"3.move left"<<endl;
cout<<"4.move right"<<endl;
cin>>movement;

    switch(movement)
    {
    case 1:
        if(x>0)
        {
        x=x-1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        if(x<9)
        {
        x=x+1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 3:
        if(y>0)
        {
        y=y-1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 4:
        if(y<9)
        {
        y=y+1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;


    }
    turn++;



}

void moveEnemy(int a, int b,int turn)
{
int eMovement=0;

cout<<"Enemy Location X "<<a<<" Y "<<b<<endl;
cout<<"1.move up"<<endl;
cout<<"2.move down"<<endl;
cout<<"3.move left"<<endl;
cout<<"4.move right"<<endl;
cin>>eMovement;

    switch(eMovement)
    {
    case 1:
        if(a>0)
        {
        a=a-1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        if(a<9)
        {
        a=a+1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 3:
        if(b>0)
        {
        b=b-1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;

        case 4:
        if(b<9)
        {
        b=b+1;
        system("cls");
        }
        else
            {
            cout<<"where are you going your leaving the battlefield"<<endl;
            cout<<"please make another selection"<<endl;
            }
        break;


    }
    turn=1;



}
```

Comment: When you debug your code, where does it go wrong?

Comment: Actually it compiles fine when I am selecting a movement option for either player neither the 'd' or the 's' characters change position... I think it may be calling the displayArray() wrong somewhere but I cant find it. Thanks for the questing @PaulMcKenzie instead of just looking at this and down voting it.

Comment: Well, "compiling fine" only means that the program has no syntax errors. It doesn't mean the program will run correctly. That is when you need to use your debugger to debug into the functions and see where they go wrong. Given you wrote the code, you must know what every line does, what every function call does, know the entire flow of the program, etc. If there is an issue, then you know what to look for and where the program goes wrong since again, you wrote the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2-player version, the `moveBoat` and `moveEnemy` functions are not doing what you're expecting. They are modifying the input parameters (e.g., `y=y+1`), but those parameters are passed by value. So the `displayArray` function is never getting the updated values.

If you pass the position parameters by reference, you should see the right behavior. For example:

```
void moveBoat(int& x, int& y, int turn);
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of this... not asking you to build my project but if you could steer me a little closer that would be appriciated

Comment: Alright so I read up on passing by referance and applied it to my code both pieces move now.... however when each piece moves the two pieces swap positions.... any ideas?

Comment: Never mind my last comment after reading about passing by reference I realized my mistake and have changed the code around and It works flawlessly thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You work too hard. Here are somethings that might help.The less code you have the Eaiser it is to manage.

use one function to check if a move is valid.

```
bool is_move_on_the_board(x, y, max_x, max_y) { //assume 0 as the starting points
    return x > = 0 && x < max_x && y > = 0 && y < max_y;
}
```

Have one function to Move

```
void move(x, y, a, b) {
    if(!is_move_on_the_board(a, b, 10, 10)) return; //invalid move
    //check if d and s collide if needed
    std::swap(Array[x][y], Array[a][b]);
}
```